# Ops agent gives only metrics but not logs

Tags: google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-ops-agent

As per the documentation, the Ops agent provides both metrics and logs. However, when installed in the VM I'm seeing only metrics but not logs.

Added the following config to the /etc/google-cloud-ops-agent/config.yaml and restarted the google-cloud-ops-agent agent

```
  receivers:
    mylog:
      type: files
      include_paths:
      - /var/log/audit/audit.log
  service:
    pipelines:
      my_pipeline:
        receivers: [mylog]
```

I'm not seeing any error message in the /var/log/google-cloud-ops-agent/subagents/logging-module.log and I exec "sudo systemctl status google-cloud-ops-agent"*"" to confirm all the components are running.

`Ops agent version google-cloud-ops-agent 2.29.0 1.el7 x86_64`

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are any logging exclusions defined in the Log Router. If you're not seeing any errors in the `/var/log/google-cloud-ops-agent/subagents/logging-module.log` and seeing traffic for the Cloud Logging API, then logging exclusions could be the cause.